# How do I view a request coming into my Postman mock server?

Tags: post, request, postman, mockserver

My website is making post requests to Postman's mock server. I want to be able to see my request to make sure that it is coming across in the way that I expect. I have tried attaching a monitor but that doesn't show me the request anywhere that I am able to find.

**Where in the Postman Windows client can I see a request coming in to my Postman mock server?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is now possible to view logs for requests made to and responses sent from your Postman mock server.

Mock Call Logs - https://blog.postman.com/introducing-postman-mock-call-logs/

Answer (score 4):

I contacted Postman support and they say currently what I want to do is not possible. See this link for information: [Postman Support Twitter Response](https://twitter.com/a85/status/1009902580640567296)

They did say however that if I wanted to just see the request that I am sending that I can use [Postman Echo](https://docs.postman-echo.com) to see what kind of request I am sending.

Comment: I can't believe this feature isn't supported.  What's the point of mocking a service in order to isolate a dependency for development and testing purposes if you can't even capture what's being sent back and forth.  It seems so trivial to implement.  Now I have to jack with setting up proxies on my QA web servers or substitute some third party tool like https://beeceptor.com or mockbin.org just to see traffic and then keep that collection in sync manually with my postman collection??  God I hate web development.  /rant

Answer (score 0):

You can see request to your mock end points buy doing the following.

1. Open postman, in the left most menu/column select mock servers
   2)Click on Mock Servers and in the second left most column you should see your mock servers
   3)Click on the one you want and in the middle screed you should see the logs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wymNX.png)

Comment: There does not seem to be a way to clear out the logs.  you have to delete and readd a new mock server but that means recreating all of your mock endpoints.  I need to experiment to see if I can just recreate the root URL related to the server name and leave the endpoints alone:

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy, this functionality was added way back in 2020.

Just click on the Mock Server and you should be able to see the logs on the right side.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Isn't [interceptor](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/capturing_http_requests) a good decision for it?

Comment: I tried following that blog and I still don't see my requests. How do I put the interceptor between my website (which isn't hosted on my local machine) and Postman's mock server (which I assume is hosted somewhere else too)

Comment: I really only want to see the requests that come into the mock server. In my mind it doesn't make sense for postman to not have some kind of tool to see requests hitting their own servers.

Comment: what about Fiddler? I guess it will definitely help you